# How to make CTAS and CVAS tables and views created through SQL lab auto-refresh

Tags: apache-superset

Context:
I use SQL lab to generate a table for charting but the it often times out when I connect the SQL query result (through explore) to multiple charts in a dash. So I try to use CTAS and CVAS in superset to create a middle layer table for charting to use which loads much faster. But the problem is that it doesn't refresh when new data comes in.

Current solution: I have searched for a week in the internet and found no relevant solution so far.

The Problem:
How to make CTAS and CVAS tables and views created through SQL lab auto-refresh?

Comment: Please show what you have tried yet.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what to do so haven't tried anything yet. It just won't refresh.

Comment: I would suggest adding that to the question, because my questions were often downvoted for the same reason. Have a good time on Stack Overflow!

Comment: OK, done. What happened when a question is downvoted?

Comment: You can find the detailed info here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down#:~:text=Downvote%20answers%20that%20are%20incorrect,all%2C%20and%20should%20be%20flagged.